# How to transfer/apply GNOME Terminal colors to KDE Konsole?

Tags: colors, kde, gnome-terminal, color-profiles, konsole

I need to use GNOME Terminal colors in KDE Konsole.

I'm not sure exactly where I can get an up-to-date color palette from GNOME Terminal, but I guess this might work: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/blame/master/src/terminal-profile-editor.cc?ref_type=heads#L198

```cc
static const GdkRGBA terminal_palettes[TERMINAL_PALETTE_N_BUILTINS][PALETTE_SIZE] =
{
  /* Based on GNOME 3.32 palette: https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/icon-design.html.en#palette */
  {
    COLOR (0x1e, 0x1e, 0x1e),  /* Suggested background for contrast */
    COLOR (0xc0, 0x1c, 0x28),  /* Red 4 */
    COLOR (0x26, 0xa2, 0x69),  /* Green 5 */
    COLOR (0xa2, 0x73, 0x4c),  /* Blend of Brown 2 and Brown 3 */
    COLOR (0x12, 0x48, 0x8b),  /* Blend of Blue 5 and Dark 4 */
    COLOR (0xa3, 0x47, 0xba),  /* Purple 3 */
    COLOR (0x2a, 0xa1, 0xb3),  /* Linear addition Blue 5 + Green 5, darkened slightly */
    COLOR (0xff, 0xff, 0xff),  /* Light 1 */
    COLOR (0x5e, 0x5c, 0x64),  /* Dark 2 */
    COLOR (0xf6, 0x61, 0x51),  /* Red 1 */
    COLOR (0x33, 0xd1, 0x7a),  /* Green 3 */
    COLOR (0xe9, 0xad, 0x0c),  /* Blend of Yellow 4 and Yellow 5 */
    COLOR (0x2a, 0x7b, 0xde),  /* Blend of Blue 3 and Blue 4 */
    COLOR (0xc0, 0x61, 0xcb),  /* Purple 2 */
    COLOR (0x33, 0xc7, 0xde),  /* Linear addition Blue 4 + Green 4, darkened slightly */
    COLOR (0xd0, 0xcf, 0xcc)   /* Blend of Light 3 and Light 4 */
  },
```

— 16 colors in total.

Now I need to turn them into a KDE Konsole palette, but I don't understand how the colors from above correspond with what is displayed in the Konsole Color Scheme editor:

[image]

Any ideas, folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of studying GNOME Terminal's source, I'd rather recommend to simply open its Preferences dialog, switch to its Colors tab and click on the colors to get their hex values (such as e.g. `#ff0000`). You should copy these one-by-one to Konsole's color picker.

By opening the graphical Preferences dialog of GNOME Terminal, it should be more obvious which color corresponds to which color of Konsole as opposed to by studying its source.

(What you found in its source is correct, but you don't see their actual colors there, you have to locate the built-in palette you wish to go with, the default foreground+background colors are defined elsewhere, and you have to convert from that format to the standard one. That's why I don't recommend to go from here.)

The mapping isn't exactly 1:1, though.

Konsole's "Intense Foreground" probably matches GNOME Terminal's "Bold color", but I'm not entirely sure. I'm not sure what Konsole's "Intense Background" stands for either, it's probably something that GNOME Terminal doesn't have.

The "Color" and "Intense color" columns of Konsole, in the "Color 1" to "Color 8" rows, matches the "Color palette" of GNOME Terminal, just laid out vertically rather than horizontally.

"Faint color" is a rarely used concept. Konsole allows you to configure each of them. GNOME Terminal uses a hardwired formula, I think each of the R, G and B hex values are 2/3 of the value of the normal color in the same row. You can compute these manually if you wish to. E.g. `#ff0000` is hex `ff` in the red channel, that's decimal 255, it's 2/3 is 170 decimal, `aa` hex. The green and blue channels are 0 which remains 0. So it becomes `#aa0000`.

Also note that GNOME Terminal has a "Show bold text in bright colors" checkbox, disabled by default in recent versions, but I'm not sure Konsole supports its equivalent behavior, I think (I might be wrong though) it always behaves like when it's enabled in GNOME Terminal. Konsole has a "Draw intense colors in bold font", but that's the other way around, which in my firm opinion is a wrong concept.

So you won't be able to get to 100% exactly the same behavior, but this is how you can configure the colors to be as close as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's funny that I was missing an obvious click-on-color action to see both color and its hex value, it's much easier. I also came across an extremely interesting tool: https://terminal.sexy/ which one can use to create palettes for different programs.

Comment: I ended up with an installable Konsole color scheme: https://www.pling.com/p/2125789/
Thanks again!